# Refer a dll which is inside another dll in WPF

Tags: wpf, dll, reference

How  to refer a dll which is inside another dll in WPF?
For example if I have two dlls A.dll and B.dll.
A.dll contains a reference to B.dll and I build A.dll. Now I want to get a component in B.dll from A.dll

I use as

```
/A;component/B;component/Original.xaml"
```

But it is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reference an assembly in .Net it doesn't get stored as a resource in the referencing assembly. If you want to reference a xaml resource in the `B` assembly, you can use the path:

```
/B;component/Original.xaml
```

Comment: Let me know if you need any clarification